# React state resets back to initial value after component is mounted

Tags: reactjs, react-lifecycle

My component is a header that contains primary and secondary navigation. So far I am dealing with primary navigation only, which chooses between large sections of the website. The state is lifted up to the main Header component, while the UpperMenu component only receives event listener and active link ID as props.

The problem is that while the state changes are conducted correctly, when the mounting is executed, the state gets changed back to initial value. This causes a "blink" in CSS, meaning that the view is rendered correctly and after a tiny second it goes back to the initial link being selected. I don't know what can possibly cause such behavior and would appreciate help.

**Header.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import UpperMenu from './UpperMenu';
import TopHeader from './TopHeader';
import styles from './Header.css';

const sections = [ 
  ["/sec0","section0"],
  ["/sec1","section1"],
  ["/sec2","section2"]
];

class Header extends React.Component {

constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {section: 0,
                submenu: 0};
}
// HERE THE STATE IS SET CORRECTLY
onSectionClick(event){
  console.log(event.target.id);
  this.setState({section:event.target.id[8]},
                 function () {console.log(this.state);});
}

// HERE PROBLEMS OCCUR, STATE IS INITIAL
componentDidMount(){
  console.log(this.state);
}

render() {
    return ( 
      <header id={styles.header}>
        <TopHeader />
        <UpperMenu  sections={sections} 
                    activeSection={sections[this.state.section][1]} 
                    onSectionClick={this.onSectionClick.bind(this)}/>
      </header>
    );
  };
 }

 export default Header;
```

**UpperMenu.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from './UpperMenu.css';
import {Link} from 'react-router';

class UpperMenu extends React.Component{

  render(){
   var activeSection = this.props.activeSection;
   var onSectionClick = this.props.onSectionClick;
   var sectionIndex = -1;

   return(
     <div className={styles.mmenu}>
       <ul className={styles.normal}>
         {this.props.sections.map(function(section){
            sectionIndex++;
            return( 
              <li key={section[1]}
                  id={"section_" + sectionIndex}
                  className={(activeSection === section[1]) ? styles.active : ""}
                  onClick={onSectionClick}>
                  <a id={"section_" + sectionIndex + "_a"}
                     href={section[0]}>{section[1]}</a>
              </li>
           )})}
       </ul>
    </div>);
    }
   }

export default UpperMenu;
```

P.S. I have tried to debug the lifecycle to determine at which point this happens and the problem begins at the **componentDidMount**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because when you click on the link, the page is re-render and thus the state is resetted to the initial state.

You can fix this by change the `a` tag to `react-router`'s [`Link`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/Link.md) (still wodering why did you import it and use `a` tag).

**Explanation:**

1. When you click on the link (`a` tag) the browser (not `React-Router`) routes you to the "mysite/sectionX" page, like a normal static website.
2. When the browser rerendered the new page, the state of all components is at its initial state. `React-Router` reads the route in the URL and route you to the component of that section.

If you use `Link`, the `react-router` (not the browser), will take care of the routing and changing the URL, only the routed component will be rerendered and the state is kept.

Comment: Hey, that Link change was the next thing for me to implement after I fixed the render problem =) I wanted to do it once everything was rendered fine. I had no idea that the <a> tag was causing the problem and that the Link is actually a SOLUTION to  this, not just the next step =) Thanks a lot!!

Comment: No problem! People usually forget that the routing in SPA is done by History API and normally not applicable by `a` tag.  :)